Vuong test for non-nested linear mixed-effect regession model (lme4), using the nonnest2 library
I would like to compare a pair of non-nested models that I fit using lme4 in R.
I would like to apply the Vuong test (1989) for that.
It seems like the nonnest2 package is the only one that supports models from lme4. However, it seems like there's an issue - either with dependencies or my models. I can't quite figure it out.
Here's an example of my code.

library(lme4)
library(nonnest2)
library(merDeriv)

                             
m_1 <- lmer(LogRT ~ surprisal_S + covariate + (1|SubjectID) + (1 | UniqueWordID),                            data=df, REML=FALSE)

m_2 <- lmer(LogRT ~ surprisal_T + covariate + (1|SubjectID) + (1 | UniqueWordID),                            data=df, REML=FALSE)

# follow the docs
vcl <- function(obj) vcov(obj, full=TRUE)
vuongtest(m_1, m_2, vc1=vcl, vc2=vcl, nested=FALSE)


The error is either "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 76.4 Gb" or it just kills the script.
Each of the two models I'm trying to compare is about 5.4 MB in size once I save them as RDS files.
I followed the documentation, but haven't found a working example.

You didn't give a reproducible example.  This minimal example works, and seems to share the essential characteristics of your case, so we will need to have a reproducible example.
require(nonnest2)
require(lme4)
require(merDeriv)

vcl <- function(obj) vcov(obj, full=TRUE)
sleepstudy$x <- rnorm(nrow(sleepstudy))
m_1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy, REML=FALSE)
m_2 <- update(m_1, . ~ . - Days + x)

vuongtest(m_1, m_2, vc1=vcl, vc2=vcl, nested=FALSE)

results
Model 1 
 Class: lmerMod 
 Call: lmer(formula = Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy, ...

Model 2 
 Class: lmerMod 
 Call: lmer(formula = Reaction ~ (1 | Subject) + x, data = sleepstudy, ...

Variance test 
  H0: Model 1 and Model 2 are indistinguishable 
  H1: Model 1 and Model 2 are distinguishable 
    w2 = 10.087,   p = 1.79e-05

Non-nested likelihood ratio test 
  H0: Model fits are equal for the focal population 
  H1A: Model 1 fits better than Model 2 
    z = 4.304,   p = 8.4e-06
  H1B: Model 2 fits better than Model 1 
    z = 4.304,   p = 1

From sessionInfo():
other attached packages:
[1] merDeriv_0.2-4 lavaan_0.6-17  sandwich_3.1-0 lme4_1.1-35.3  Matrix_1.7-0  
[6] nonnest2_0.5-6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 lattice_0.22-6      splines_4.5.0      
 [4] bspm_0.5.7          zoo_1.8-12          pbivnorm_0.6.0     
 [7] stats4_4.5.0        CompQuadForm_1.4.3  mvtnorm_1.2-4      
[10] nloptr_2.0.3        grid_4.5.0          mnormt_2.1.1       
[13] compiler_4.5.0      boot_1.3-30         nlme_3.1-164       
[16] minqa_1.2.6         Rcpp_1.0.12         quadprog_1.5-8     
[19] MASS_7.3-60.0.1    


Thank you very much. Is there a way to make my example reproducible with my own models?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6699112/190277 for information about sharing/simulating moderate- to large-sized data sets for reproducing model fitting problems. Editing your question to include more details about your data set (e.g. summary(df)) would be a good first step.
